# Copying development files from single Sitecore's CM server (Views, JS,CSS, bin, etc..) to multiple CD servers automatically?

Tags: site-configuration

Beside manually uploading updated development files (Views,CSS, JS,etc..) to multiple CD servers (on the same network / domain) through FTP which is a very hectic process, or using an external tools like files replication scripts or tools?

Is there is any DIRECT way to be configured on Sitecore to publish development files automatically to multiple CD servers? In our case it's 2 CD servers with a load balancer included

I understand there are Sitecore pipelines and Sitecore Queues, is this helpful in our case ? Would appreciate some light shading on this subject.

Thank you

Comment: No, this should be done via your deployment process. Sitecore publishing is content only. This should never be done manually!

Comment: Thanks for replying ! 
Can you please provide some more details ?

Comment: In general, you should have a deployment pipline/DevOps/CI-CD (whatever you want to call it). This process is automated and pulls from your source control. Typically, you have a branch or GitHub action that will fire at a certain point when you are ready to go to production. It should then deploy to all your environments (CM/CD). 

You do not want your CM and CDs to be out of sync. CM is not a development environment, it is your production authoring. It needs to match your running website.